# Mysql query ignoring NULL and empty fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very crazy query I know, but when I run it it returns all matches regardless of whether or not field mvideo is empty or not.

the query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `weaponsprojects` 
WHERE mvideo != "" 
  AND credit7 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit2 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit3 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit4 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit5 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit6 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit1 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit8 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit9 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit10 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit11 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit12 = "' .$person. '"
   ORDER BY usort'
```

and it returns when any of the credits equal the person but it completely ignores the mvideo part.  Why is this??

Edit: the field is not NULL, just simply empty no spaces just blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think that the `WHERE` condition is logically flawed... you need some precedence     here, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `weaponsprojects` 
WHERE mvideo != "" 
  AND (credit7 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit2 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit3 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit4 = "' .$person. '" 
   OR credit5 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit6 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit1 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit8 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit9 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit10 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit11 = "' .$person. '"
   OR credit12 = "' .$person. '")
   ORDER BY usort'
```

by adding the `(` and the `)` we tell the `WHERE` statement: "either `mvideo` is not empty and it matches one of the `OR` statements"

Comment: Brillant it worked, had no idea I could do that, makes total sense though